# backbone localstorage is undefined

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, local-storage

I 'm trying write a simple RSS using backbone.js &  localstorage. I am having trouble saving the form values to the localstorage.

I 'm using [this](https://github.com/Jesse-Breuer/Backbone.js-localStorage/blob/master/script.js) & [this](http://coenraets.org/blog/2011/12/backbone-js-wine-cellar-tutorial-part-1-getting-started/) as my reference.

On saving the data i get the following error

```
Resource failed to load 
    b.ajaxTransport.send jquery-1.9.1.min.js:5
    b.extend.ajax jquery-1.9.1.min.js:5
    g.ajax backbone-min.js:41
    g.sync backbone-min.js:41
    Backbone.sync backbone.localStorage.js:190
    f.extend.sync backbone-min.js:12
    f.extend.save backbone-min.js:16
    Backbone.View.extend.saveSource app.js:47
    b.event.dispatch jquery-1.9.1.min.js:3
    b.event.add.v.handle jquery-1.9.1.min.js:3
```

**VIEW**

```
var sourceView = Backbone.View.extend({
   tagName:"li",

   template:_.template($('#tmpl_sourceDetails').html()), 

   initialize: function () {
        console.log(this.model);
        this.model.bind("change", this.render, this);
    },

    render: function (eventName) {
        $(this.el).html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        return this;
    },

    events: {
            "change input": "change",
            "click .save": "saveSource",
            "click .delete": "deleteSource"
    },

    change: function (event) {
        var target = event.target;
        console.log('changing ' + target.id + ' from: ' + target.defaultValue + ' to: ' + target.value);

    },

    saveSource: function () {
        console.log(this.model);
        if (this.model.isNew()) {
            var self = this;
            site = $('#name').val();
            siteURL = $('#sourceURL').val(); 
        this.model.save({source:site,sourceURL:siteURL});
        this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        } else {
            this.model.save();
        console.log(this.Collections.length);   
        }
        return false;
       },

    deleteSource: function () {
        this.model.destroy({
            success: function () {
                alert('RSS source deleted successfully');
                window.history.back();
            }
        });
        return false;
    },

    close: function () {
        $(this.el).unbind();
        $(this.el).empty();
    }
});
```

**COLLECTION**

```
//indicates collection
//localstorage table defined here
var RSSCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: RSS,
    url: "../api/RSS",
    localStorage: new Store("tblSource")// saving all items under tblSource namespace.

});
```

**UPDATE**
I think the error is because of model.localStorage being undefined. On save instead of calling backbone.localSync it is calling Backbone.ajaxSync

```
backbone.localStorage.js 
    Backbone.getSyncMethod = function(model) {
      if(model.localStorage || (model.collection && model.collection.localStorage)) {
        return Backbone.localSync;
      }

      return Backbone.ajaxSync;
    };
```

Any ideas/suggestions where I 'm going wrong?
Thanks

Comment: are you sure your files are added in the correct order? According to the stack trace, the call to Backbone.Sync is making an ajax request. In case of Local Storage, that shouldn't be the case.

Comment: Yes, please look at my update.

Comment: is your order correct? like in here: https://github.com/Jesse-Breuer/Backbone.js-localStorage/blob/master/index.htm ?

Comment: Has your model been added to the collection? If not, Backbone.localStorage won't find the localStorage to save to and will delegate to ajaxSync.